# Prevent duplicating code in subclass using Timer Elapsed

Tags: c#

I have a base class which performs a `Timer` `Elapsed` call. Subclasses of this class also perform a `Timer` `Elapsed` call after the base class has finished. The base class sets a protected boolean which the subclass uses to determine if it needs to continue. See code below.

```
    protected virtual async void OnTimerElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
      if (someCondition) {
          isValid = false;
      }
      else {
          isValid = true;
      }

      if (!isValid)
      {
         return;
      }
    }
```

```
    protected override async void OnTimerElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
      base.OnTimerElapsed(sender, e);

      if (!isValid)
      {
        return;
      }
    }
```

I want to somehow eliminate the need for the `if` statement in the override function in the subclass, but I suspect there is no clean way to do this.

Does this appear to be the best way of doing this?

I've tried thinking about different ways of writing this, but because the Timer.Elapsed function is natively `void`, I couldn't think of other ways...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make OnTimerElapsed private and make the subsequent processing virtual.
Example code (I ignore async for simplicity):

```
public class BaseClass
{
    private bool _isValid;

    private bool Validate() { ... }

    private void OnTimerElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        _isValid = Validate();
        if (!_isValid)
        {
            return;
        }

        DoProcessingWhenValid();
    }

    protected virtual void DoProcessingWhenValid() { ... }
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    protected override void DoProcessingWhenValid();
    {
        base.DoProcessingWhenValid();
        // More work here.
    }
}
```

Note that technically you don't even need `_isValid` in this simple scenario, but it might make sense to still have the field, and potentially for it to remain protected (or even `protected { get; private set; }` if you want to get fancy).

The net result of this is that you only check `_isValid` once, in the base class.  All derived classes can assume that `DoProcessingWhenValid` is only called when `_isValid` is true.  If desired, you can pass the `sender` and `ElapsedEventArgs` into `DoProcessingWhenValid`, if the processing needs some of the information.

Comment: Thanks! I don't know how I failed to see to do this... Probably the timer elapsed threw me off. Nicely done!